# Cause of "Could not load file or....Access is denied." IIS error?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, access-denied

The website I write code for encountered a problem today on a web server running IIS 7; it got a "Could not load file or assembly...Access is denied" error.  This is the first time I've seen it, however, when the file in question was actually present in the bin folder.

I don't have direct access to the event log (that's our Networking dept's domain), so I asked them to send me the log of the errors over.

As a programmer, I don't see much useful in the log.  The only part that I think might be of interest is the Request Information:

```
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

I really don't see anything abnormal about any of it, but IIS isn't my forte.  This DLL has been on the server for about 2 years now and this is the first time I've seen the error thrown.

Also, only one page on the site uses this file, but none of the pages throwing the error do.  I'm guessing I was accessing cached versions of the other pages?

I'm just looking for possibilities that I can pass on for future reference, as the server isn't really my responsibility...of course, the website itself is, so if it breaks, it's all of our problem.  Thanks for anything you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime exceptions in asp.net applications generally do not show up in the error log. Ask your networking department for the warning log; it should contain the information you are looking for.

Comment: We did this and didn't come up with anything.  Unfortunately, I think it's just something that we'll have to debug some more the next time this occurs.